# Lista Doble en Pascal

Tags: lista, pascal, freepascal

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de listas. El ejercicio me pide crear una lista doble de enteros. Me esta costando hacerlo y creo que lo hice mal. 
Leo los enteros de un archivo armando una lista comun y luego copia la lista al reves...
A ver si alguien me puede dar un opinion.

```
Program G4E10;
Uses Crt;
Type
    ListEnt = ^TipoEntero;
    TipoEntero = record
        ant : ListEnt;
        int : Integer;
        sig : ListEnt;
        end;
    T_Lista = record
        Cbeza : ListEnt;
        Cola : ListEnt;
    end;
    Procedure Crear(var Lista: T_Lista);
        var Arch: Text; NuevoDato, Ant,Act: ListEnt;
        begin
        Lista.Cbeza := nil;
        Lista.Cola := nil;
        Assign(Arch, 'ENTEROS.txt');
        Reset(Arch);
        while not Eof(Arch) do 
            begin
            Ant := nil;
            Act := Lista.Cbeza;
            New(NuevoDato);
            Readln(Arch, NuevoDato^.int);
            while (Act <> nil) AND (Act^.int < NuevoDato^.int) do
                begin
                Ant := Act;
                Act := Act^.sig;
                end;
            if (Act = Lista.Cbeza) then
                begin
                NuevoDato^.sig := Act;
                NuevoDato^.ant := nil;
                Lista.Cbeza := NuevoDato;
                end
            else    
                begin
                NuevoDato^.ant := Ant;
                NuevoDato^.sig := Act;
                Ant^.sig := NuevoDato;
                end;
            end;
        Close(Arch);
        end;
    Procedure MostrarDer(Lista: T_Lista);
    begin
        while (Lista.Cbeza <> nil) do
            begin
            Writeln(Lista.Cbeza^.int, ' ');
            Lista.Cbeza := Lista.Cbeza^.sig;
            end;
            Writeln;
    end;
    Procedure MostrarIzq(Lista: T_Lista);
    begin
        while (Lista.Cola <> nil) do
            begin
            Writeln(Lista.Cola^.int, ' ');
            Lista.Cola := Lista.Cola^.ant;
            end;
        Writeln;
    end;
    Procedure CreaD(var Lista:T_Lista);
    var Aux1, Aux2: ListEnt;
    begin
    Aux1 := Lista.Cbeza;
    while (Aux1 <> nil) do
        begin
        Aux2 := Lista.Cola;
        New(Lista.Cola);
        Lista.Cola := Aux1;
        Lista.Cola^.ant := Aux2;
        Aux1 := Aux1^.sig;
        end;
    end;
var Lista: T_Lista;
begin
Clrscr;
Crear(Lista);
CreaD(Lista);
MostrarDer(Lista);
MostrarIzq(Lista);
Readln;
end.
```

Se debe hacer de otra forma verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, este es un ejercicio de "Listas Enlazadas". El concepto de estas listas es: Tenemos un tipo de datos que contiene un puntero a la dirección anterior, siguiente y el registro de lo que deseamos guardar. Me voy a concentrar en dos procedimientos que creaste: Crear y Mostrar.
Para crear, en el primer ciclo, reservamos memoria para nuestro primer registro. "Anterior" va a ser nulo y vamos a guardar la dirección que apunta a la "Cabecera" del primer puntero. en los demás registros asignamos las variables "siguientes". Cuando terminamos de leer el archivo obtenemos la posición de la "Cola".

el código para esto sería algo así:

```
Procedure Crear(var Lista: T_Lista);
    var 
        Arch: Text; 
        NuevoDato, Ant,Act: ListEnt;
        primero:Boolean;
    begin
        Lista.Cbeza := nil;
        Lista.Cola := nil;
        Assign(Arch, 'ENTEROS.txt');
        Reset(Arch);
        Ant:=nil;
        Act:=nil;
        Primero:=True;

        while not Eof(Arch) do
        begin
            if primero then
            begin
                primero:=False;
                New(NuevoDato);
                Readln(Arch, NuevoDato^.int);
                NuevoDato^.ant:=nil;
                Lista.Cbeza:=NuevoDato;
            end
            else
            begin
                New(NuevoDato);
                Readln(Arch, NuevoDato^.int);
                act:=NuevoDato;
                NuevoDato:=Ant;
                NuevoDato^.Sig:=act;
                NuevoDato:=Act;
                NuevoDato^.Ant:=ant;
            end;
            ant:=nuevodato;                       
        end;    
        Close(Arch);
        Lista.Cola:=NuevoDato;  
    end;
```

Tene en cuenta que las variables argumentos de procedimientos nunca las utilizaste como tal.

Para mostrar los elementos, el puntero debe posicionarse por ejemplo en la primera posición y recorrer hasta el final de la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```
        NuevoDato:=Lista.Cbeza;
        primero:=true;
        while primero do
        begin
            if NuevoDato=Lista.Cola then primero:=false;

            writeln(Nuevodato^.int);
            Nuevodato:=Nuevodato^.sig;
        end;
```

Particularmente, en este ejercicio, yo tomaría como referencia dos variables globales para cada una de la lista y dos variables globales para la "Cabeza" y "Cola". Una vez que estos conceptos estén claros podes hacer las cosas mas difíciles.